# Does it make sense to run an hbase mapreduce job with a million Scans?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I have a dataset in hbase which is large enough that it takes a couple hours to run a mapreduce job on the entire dataset. I'd like to be able to break down the data using precomputed indexes: once a day map the entire data set and break it down into multiple indexes:

- 1% sample of all users
- All users who are participating in a particular A/B experiment
- All users on the nightly prerelease channel.
- All users with a paticular addon (or whatever criterion we're interested in this week)

My thought was to just store a list of row IDs for the relevant records, and then later people can do little mapreduce jobs on just those rows. But a 1% sample is still 1M rows of data, and I'm not sure how to construct a mapreduce job on a list of a million rows.

Does it make any sense to create a table mapper job using initTableMapperJob(List scans) if there are going to be a million different Scan objects which make up the query? Are there other ways to do this so that I can still farm out the computation and I/O to the hbase cluster efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do a million scans.  If you have a million non-contiguous ids, you could run a map/reduce job over the list of ids using a custom input format so that you divide the list up into a reasonable number of partitions (I would guess 4x the number of your m/r slots, but that number is not based on anything).  That would give you a million get operations, which is probably better than a million scans.

If you are lucky enough to have a more reasonable number of contiguous ranges, then scans would be better than straight gets

Comment: David, that's good advice, and I have a follow question:
I thought that one of the benefits of hbase mapreduce is that the map jobs would run on the same nodes as the data was stored in hbase/hadoop. Is this true? And is there a way to partition my input so that this is still true and minimize the cross-node I/O?

Comment: Sure.  It is less trivial than a standard M/R job with a TableInputFormat because you will have to set up the node affinity yourself in a custom input format. The good news is that TableInputFormat is open source and you should be able to steal most of the logic from there